# How can I keep a deadbolt functional in a door that moves with the seasons?

Tags: doors

I have a garage man door that shifts so much in winter that I cannot unlock the deadbolt to open the door.
I think it shifts up due to the frost/thaw cycles during the cold winter. Everything goes back to normal by spring.

You can see by the pictures that the floor has cracked in that area as well. The floor is pushing the whole door up causing the deadbolt to be pushed right up to the top of the deadbolt strike plate.

I'm going to put in a larger hole strike plate this spring.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I could do to help reduce the amount of shift in the concrete?
Chip some of it out, throw some rebar in there and repour under the door?

Open to any ideas!

[image: Bottom of the Door]

[image: DoorFrame]

Comment: My first recommendation is to check your drainage and see if you can reduce the amount of moisture getting under the slab.  That should reduce or eliminate the heaving that is your root problem.

Comment: Thanks. I agree and I'm going to do some landscaping this spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My folks have the same issue. They have a lot of moisture in clay soil, and even with modern frost footings this happens. There's really no hope of preventing seasonal movement.

I think enlarging your strike plate bore is the right fix. Be sure to maintain security by installing a thicker plate if needed.